# Is it possible to use route parameter in route naming in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-controller

I am trying invokable controller in Laravel :

```
php artisan make:controller ProvisionServer --invokable
```

And I want to do something like :

```
Route::get('/proviser/{page}',[App\Http\Controllers\ProvisionServer::class, '__invoke'])
       ->name('proviser.'.$page)
       ->where('page','index|about|contact');
```

In order to call 'About' url like

```
route('proviser.about')
```

Obviously, this seems not working. I get

> Undefined variable $page

Is there anyway to do it ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make `$pages` array and defined router  like this

```php
$pages = ['index','about','contact'];
foreach($pages as $page){
    Route::get('proviser/'.$page,[App\Http\Controllers\ProvisionServer::class, '__invoke'])
       ->name('proviser.'.$page);
}
```